# Angular 2 edit bound value on paste only works at certain times

Tags: angular

I using Angular 2.0.0-rc.1 and am trying to build a simple component which encapsulates the behavior of a an input field which only allows integer values. (HTML5 input type=number will not work for me in this case).

I've managed to get the component to block non-digit keys as they are pressed. I want to do the same for pasted values but only manages to make it work occasionally. I've thrown together a Typescript Plunker which illustrates the problem: https://plnkr.co/edit/6H2iSs55yNyA2TQWqKlb.

Any tips are greatly appreciated!

```
import{ Component } from '@angular/core'

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  providers: [],
  template: `
    <div>
    <p>
    Typing values into the input field successfully filters out non-digit characters. Pasting non-digit characters should clear the input but only does so occasionally, why?
    </p>
    <p>
    Try pasting a non-digit string into the input. Works right? Now past the same value again. *sad face*
    </p>
      <input type="text" [ngModel]="value" (ngModelChange)="onValueChange($event)" (paste)="onPaste($event)" (keypress)="onKeyPress($event)" >
      <ul>
        <li *ngFor="let item of items">{{item}}</li>
      </ul>  
    </div>
  `
})
export class App {
  public value: number = 42;
  public items = [];
  private _isPasting = false;

  onKeyPress(event: KeyboardEvent) {
      let char = String.fromCharCode(typeof event.charCode === 'undefined' ? event.keyCode : event.charCode);
      let match = this.isInteger(char);
      if (!match) {
          event.preventDefault();
      }
  }

  onPaste(value) {
    this._isPasting = true;
  }

  onValueChange(value) {
    if(this._isPasting && !this.isInteger(value)) {
      this.value = '';
    } else {
      this.items.push(value);
    }
    this._isPasting = false;
  }

  isInteger(value: string): boolean {
    return /^\d+$/.test(value);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the pattern attribute on your form input field. This allows you to provide a regular expression that defines you allowed inputs with greater flexibility than provided by the type attribute.

Search html5 pattern attribute for examples (sorry for some reason I can't copy in any links).

Hope that helps.

Comment: That might actually be an alternative for us since we need to support IE11 where input type=number is not supported but pattern is. Thanks for the advice! I would though really like to know why the above Angular2 code doesn't work and how I could make it work.